# Making Windows 10 recognize your app as a Default app option

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, settings

Is there any way to make my Windows Universal 10 app (C#) pop up on the Default apps tab in the Windows 10 Settings app? For instance, Microsoft Edge is my default browser but what if i made an app to replace it and i wanted it to be my default browser instead?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add file type associations to your application through the declarations tab of the app's manifest.

[image: Add file type associations]

To support your file type association, you'll need to handle the Activated method in your App.xaml.cs. You'll be able to detect if your app was activated through the file association from the File ActivationKind in the arguments passed through to that method.

Once you've done that, you'll be able to set your default programs in settings as follows:

[image: Settings File Associations]